# Error: A session id is required for this command but wasn't found in the response payload

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io, google-chrome-headless

I want to do some UI Testing with a Headless Browser Engine.
Since we don't have a graphic unit in our Linux I have used docker for  [chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/)

And I setup a test:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
const options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };

const browser = webdriverio
.remote({ host: 'localhost', port: 4444 })
.init({ browserName: 'chrome', version: '45' });

describe('webdriver.io tests', function() {
  it('is a third test', function() {
    browser.url('foo');
    expect(Promise.resolve(browser.getTitle()))
.to.eventually.equal('foo');
});
```

Test is run by:

```
BABEL_ENV=dev npm run mocha-test --recursive=tests/mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require babel-polyfill
```

But all I get is:

```
Error: A session id is required for this command but wasn't found in the response payload.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34010150/1906307) explains how to properly wait for `init` to be done.

Comment: @Louis I am on it.

Comment: @Louis Got it working, question can be deleted / closed if necessary.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Your question was closed as a duplicate 18 hours ago, around the same time I made my comment.  It is not *necessary* to delete it. Right now the community cannot delete it anyway. It takes some time after closure before the community can put in deletion votes. If you want to delete it, I think you can since you are the author of the question and it has no answers.